Cost of a private pilot
I am looking at purchasing a plane and I am trying to get the best estimate possible of what the hourly cost is going to be. I can’t seem to find any information on the cost of a pilot and I’m hoping the community can help with an estimate. Here’s the plan, I want to purchase a piper navajo chieftain for my family to use for shorter trips in our region (Northeast) and I want a hire a pilot to fly us. I know there are a bunch of variables with this question (insurance, skill level, experience w the aircraft) that will play into the cost. I’m looking for an hourly estimate I think? I’m assuming I pay for them to stay and other expenses if it’s an overnight trip? I’m just trying to get clarification to make a final hourly cost estimate. I thank you in advance and appreciate any info. I am 100% not as knowledgeable as anyone on here, so dumb it down for me please. Also, if I’m missing anything glaring please don’t hesitate.

Keep in mind that "private pilot" is a class of license that doesn't allow carrying passengers for compensation. In this scenario you would have to hire a pilot with a "commercial pilot" license.

There are dozens of factors that play into an 'hourly rate', far too many for someone to list here and come up with an estimate. Instead, find a small aircraft charter company and ask them the cost a charter for your typical use case. When you've recovered from the shock, treat this as a ball park figure. Do not assume that you can necessarily improve on it.

Where is your region? North-East USA? North-east UK? North-East Europe? This can have a substantial impact on your costs.

$200/hr just for fuel at 32 gal/hr. Triple that to get the overall fixed and hourly operating costs if it's used moderately. Maybe another 60 dollars overall for the pilot incl his/her expenses.  You can figure on 600 to 1000 dollars per hour. Not an answer because I'm just spitballing. So many variables

Northeast US. Sorry about that. I didn’t realize the pilot would need a commercial license to fly my plane, I’m sure that is going to add to the cost dramatically. My base estimate so far is about $875 hour all-in. I’ll reach out to the local charter company I currently use and ask their opinion, I know they have a few younger pilots on staff that would love the hours, I just don’t want to get taken to the cleaners by them.

Have you considered getting yourself a private pilots license? Then you could fly your family wherever you wanted to go!

Normally you wouldn't buy your own airplane and then hire a pilot occasionally; the pilot would have their own aircraft that they maintain and are familiar with and use regularly, and you'd just charter a flight when needed. You might want to just look around and see what kind of charter flight services are available near you -- in the long run it's likely cheaper than buying your own airplane.

@DarthPseudonym or you buy the aircraft AND hire the pilot to work for you as an employee, but that requires a LOT of flight time to be economical and is typically only feasible for larger corporations and rich people with international commitments.
